# Backup NAS to multiple hard drives on a Mac Mini Server

Tags: backup, mac-osx-server

I've got a Drobo 5D connected to a Mac Mini Server which holds around 14Tb of data. Right now, we've got 30Tb worth of external hard drives that we'll use to create a weekly on-site backup and a bi-weekly off-site backup.

Right now, we're doing this via rsync and on a folder-by-folder basis, but this isn't sustainable as the files move around weekly. (We're a video production outfit.)

My use case is really similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/338683/backup-strategy-for-a-large-home-server-raid-volume-across-multiple-backup-disks) but the accepted answer there did not specify which product he used and all the other answers suggested either a Windows-specific product or a software RAID.

This other [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/270170/how-would-you-backup-15tb-of-data-to-multiple-drives) is similar to the workflow that we're currently doing but that doesn't have an accepted answer and I've looked over Bacula and Amanda and they look overly complicated. Plus, it looks like I would have to set up a separate linux box for it.

I should be able to do the following:

1. Backup to external hard drive
2. Plug in external hard drive on another computer
3. Recover the files, without needing the rest of the drives or external applications

My wishlist would be the following:

- Works on Mac, natively or via brew
- Files are readable on disk, without needing the backup application
- Hopefully free, but willing to pay as long as the above are satisfied

If getting a separate backup server is unavoidable (i.e. wishlist #1 is impossible), then my hard requirement really would be that the files would be readable on disk without needing an external application.